# c functions on strings

Tags: c++

here is code to copy input string to buffer  question is how  make such that code show me result on output?
 code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using std::memset;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
void foo(char *s){
    char buf[15];
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
    strncat(buf,s,sizeof(buf)-1);



     cout<<buf;


}
int main(){


    char *s="dato";
        cout<<foo(s)<<endl;




     return 0;
}
```

mistakes

```
1>------ Build started: Project: memory_buffer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  memory_buffer.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\memory_buffer\memory_buffer.cpp(10): warning C4996: 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(175) : see declaration of 'strncat'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\memory_buffer\memory_buffer.cpp(22): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::string>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(186): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(192): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(199): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(206): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(226): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(260): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(280): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(305): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(325): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(345): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(366): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(386): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(407): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(float)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(427): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(447): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(467): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(487): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, std::string)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Why not use a `std::string`...?

Comment: @Kenny Wow, and he's got a lot of rep from it too.

Comment: @KennyTM: no one uses `std::string` in the real world. People only use `char*` and raw pointers. The same applies for classes, no one uses classes either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to create a function to print a char* to the output, simply use:

```
char *s = "dato";
cout << s << endl;
```

or even better:

```
cout << "dato" << endl;
```

The problem with your code is that you try to print a void (i.e. nothing) to the output - because your function foo returns void.

Also you shouldn't be using char* in C++ programs, use std::string instead as it is safer and you can get rid of any buffer copies:

```
#include <string>
...

std::string s = "dato";
std::string s2 = s;
cout << s2 << endl;  // Prints dato
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line would help.

```
cout<<foo(s)<<endl;
```

Function foo returns void, and cout cannot print void. Since you already print the in foo(), this statement is not needed at all.